# Gradle sync failed: connection reset

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've just updated Android Studio to 4.1.1 and encountered an issue. It crashes while Gradle is trying to sync my old projects and on a new Gradle gives me "Connection reset" error. I've disabled antivirus, checked Gradle and plugin versions and set them 6.7.1 and 4.1.1 accordingly, I've downloaded Gradle 6.7.1 manually and specified its location in File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle, non of this worked. Checked not to use any proxy. I've tried to reach those files, that Gradle "Could not get resource" manually, using browser - they exist and are downloadable. But when I try to reach "Could not GET" links, I get "Access Denied" answer:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied</Message>
</Error>
```

Well, that's where I decided to take a brake and to seek advice. The error log:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'TestApp'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc1.jar (org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-lite-metadata/0.1.0-rc1/tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/481dbf5bb38f02eef52d7ff966f55f99a980a7d58771d4852785f51bb82ce5a0?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22tensorflow-lite-metadata-0.1.0-rc1.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvNDgxZGJmNWJiMzhmMDJlZWY1MmQ3ZmY5NjZmNTVmOTlhOTgwYTdkNTg3NzFkNDg1Mjc4NWY1MWJiODJjZTVhMD9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMnRlbnNvcmZsb3ctbGl0ZS1tZXRhZGF0YS0wLjEuMC1yYzEuamFyJTIyIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNjA3MTA3MTE4fSwiSXBBZGRyZXNzIjp7IkFXUzpTb3VyY2VJcCI6IjAuMC4wLjAvMCJ9fX1dfQ__&Signature=HCd0osHkINA9D3wVIRsNYlx9c0SSOv1zPfyW98Kz~WpbUDpjKQXC1aeOt~rnQ9F2i6QKH5m-hf-Q8uLhJHqIW1~KlfPf6WLUiXhHl1Ds6MZp2Y7dRmLeiVDH8sB6AcCo43M2m3DPhaNpucJycZsIJreyxbbkCAqFmwEvpudZdk6sbvhhkJX0ke0SDtxfsQrROCSkRz3l00OMga0MGVsS~CHmFdvxG7wzoFnoefdGK9JocjYhpCH8U8myC9Ry0G1XnqsgNMNEtMgTc9O2KjCWRJ6s8eaufGKzSO83r7XM8ZxVsGtXIuu5bU9-9iYuU2L-dwD0pGGia8Qxts1L51VSHQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/7043dee4e9e7175e93e0b36f45b1ec1ecb893c5f755667e8b916eb8dd201c6ca?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvNzA0M2RlZTRlOWU3MTc1ZTkzZTBiMzZmNDViMWVjMWVjYjg5M2M1Zjc1NTY2N2U4YjkxNmViOGRkMjAxYzZjYT9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmJjcGtpeC1qZGsxNW9uLTEuNTYuamFyJTIyIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNjA3MTA3MzUzfSwiSXBBZGRyZXNzIjp7IkFXUzpTb3VyY2VJcCI6IjAuMC4wLjAvMCJ9fX1dfQ__&Signature=j9yu55JArCNVmfPOPJnYbvpOrHgNsBWg~7mTx5HY4-g84FRBNgnv~dYO0P2l9NLE33U~-dCHO1FZHhOP2M6L1AqqDPe-FQGlBKO7DoVOCpFsZSq2WavRlVYT38qsynISclrFBYBk8LeksrwtdkpMX5vO-VZmAaIZiVV8aanukuBkisbdPV5QqPe70xDOzFwAHwJRkev3Lyt703gAMheglDQFYTnF7rL4Ff5XYvng4I-MMtrzRM5zTBTVqkRY4pOHRUTKhK9Zs5fAg7k15K-TP3pzBp95Jrnp6BirLaEbgIOhuz2iWeiGD~g8BO7v5i4QhxWmoPMskRfUHoPEEkzNVA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/963e1ee14f808ffb99897d848ddcdb28fa91ddda867eb18d303e82728f878349?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvOTYzZTFlZTE0ZjgwOGZmYjk5ODk3ZDg0OGRkY2RiMjhmYTkxZGRkYTg2N2ViMThkMzAzZTgyNzI4Zjg3ODM0OT9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmJjcHJvdi1qZGsxNW9uLTEuNTYuamFyJTIyIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNjA3MTA3MzExfSwiSXBBZGRyZXNzIjp7IkFXUzpTb3VyY2VJcCI6IjAuMC4wLjAvMCJ9fX1dfQ__&Signature=V0jsJ1-7LrtmSVWuBy40OLzsrDKVVeTC2SyxEf3XSEX0lEpR2d81lctEjOLGCFdTT2qQqd2XN~cXxkdlkbolHPKXp-sq60VjSs0xrXuQ28PonG0mP3vy9tsYBR2ARngCS8VP1k7eENZfkz0K~uH7AA9PK38BqqLZLLIvPrlwUPVcmyiOtRUa13NzcuNmBnu45O9WDScV8PJY5FU5Inp~Ya47cczzynPUGYuQTkYvmYHxjXF-GQwIRnzmivgyJJp3Rb0xfuML0w6r9YHztGQTzzj20LDht~rfRjF9KVqsyde5nRx4VrmA8gwzRHRUe9~2wKv115ibiuZh8L59422WQg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download httpclient-4.5.6.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.6/httpclient-4.5.6.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/c03f813195e7a80e3608d0ddd8da80b21696a4c92a6a2298865bf149071551c7?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22httpclient-4.5.6.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvYzAzZjgxMzE5NWU3YTgwZTM2MDhkMGRkZDhkYTgwYjIxNjk2YTRjOTJhNmEyMjk4ODY1YmYxNDkwNzE1NTFjNz9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmh0dHBjbGllbnQtNC41LjYuamFyJTIyIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNjA3MTA3MzQ3fSwiSXBBZGRyZXNzIjp7IkFXUzpTb3VyY2VJcCI6IjAuMC4wLjAvMCJ9fX1dfQ__&Signature=eZ2DcEsOrEe-bw43M7EGPz-1tBt2anmbG~ZDLE5sBCc7W2Sg0c6t8jJIz9UmvyC5owJOvlwxEi5YFLgQl90gkkpXjD1tisUeGYfwyb6fhus3dghTLre9CzEvcZWP-NBA~yUCLOIzHe-9Ac2ur~wSPkRvyamq1zMT1PzDeOofGKuexL7CpNp~x6lmH7juIyqisrGN0rOU~skhoL4WTmVJQjn72suQeAi7Xtdffk8eb-ysVfPi1jYiCv8LmYhvFMXuhEEYujL4sL2kzRG-RN5SGmOS1AcTjkMEv-Z8t5uzPbjMyjmH5qjqAxGNVLzk1iNhvkZdZFczf-WSSn37jVtGmw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download httpcore-4.4.10.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.10/httpcore-4.4.10.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/78ba1096561957db1b55200a159b648876430342d15d461277e62360da19f6fd?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22httpcore-4.4.10.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvNzhiYTEwOTY1NjE5NTdkYjFiNTUyMDBhMTU5YjY0ODg3NjQzMDM0MmQxNWQ0NjEyNzdlNjIzNjBkYTE5ZjZmZD9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmh0dHBjb3JlLTQuNC4xMC5qYXIlMjIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE2MDcxMDczMTF9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn19fV19&Signature=Fb4oTnmNYeW8CvGxiDotNScOui0mnXDv4FkOsPIM5dQdhotN56VIXtgNp3fP2j4Wm9ZqzkB90CkRD8iZmvu7~~su2MJl8ulE1ZfRqgHSEa-UTCmu5KhNXxiXZ7eUjR9ADKE4VG-P8opLHs4DZ~EMJW3xJPcvaTRVk9irpdm83XkkXyCjYtSAhZWXbMLWfHH5TlGFZMQ4oV9nuuxzOFjj9yNL-beqKy6FUU0k4vDH4b6t48-1c1oxyraf-FCDD0dJ76V65-f2WxP4nOPEDOCBEZJQ8TEFVoYrjmeBjKA98T61~nPH3LDL2dDgjMRoPQxLerAFBubhn4yv~ZHLufMpMg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.72/kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/a188d9367de1c4ee9479db630985c0597b20709c83161b1430d24edb27e38c40?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvYTE4OGQ5MzY3ZGUxYzRlZTk0NzlkYjYzMDk4NWMwNTk3YjIwNzA5YzgzMTYxYjE0MzBkMjRlZGIyN2UzOGM0MD9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmtvdGxpbi1yZWZsZWN0LTEuMy43Mi5qYXIlMjIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE2MDcxMDczNDl9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn19fV19&Signature=MqJLGT9w9LPCEbfC2PaEZaJ3dMm767cbEXyxFe2sIl7r~3dRKj4xpFhh1CDtgQDT4krPbLQzuyVq7Rw7vtNr4B~XRQT2QUBnuA828wzYh9JPQUuHNtvRJxwBg0uSGQl04-yv5jIdRvUmskUdA7zDhTs4jRbkJpwc1Wm6sLlpnroMyOe~yaFSMO-Du4Qs8btgR1DkLRConkEymT423WDBCouC8C5ke8N9b5pdR7DJSMSbgk0~eCO-KhVCSlHSNLnyZQviEMBwAh0IIMsmBoMzQgieICCksASKxLU2xjrGrR4yzgLsmEaHNRdyTDeWiCsbAP91q6KjDrSKA~CmmaqngA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download antlr4-4.5.3.jar (org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/a32de739cfdf515774e696f91aa9697d2e7731e5cb5045ca8a4b657f8b1b4fb4?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22antlr4-4.5.3.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvYTMyZGU3MzljZmRmNTE1Nzc0ZTY5NmY5MWFhOTY5N2QyZTc3MzFlNWNiNTA0NWNhOGE0YjY1N2Y4YjFiNGZiND9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmFudGxyNC00LjUuMy5qYXIlMjIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE2MDcxMDcyMjN9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn19fV19&Signature=T41zmXQ8zdJLvDyn-o-8D~Zf~06PFzBjSsCmdqHcFudxTqpMsCFPbvIFg4O1NoIcdynfru0ad4tSfqH8QGo1KeuUFoDJ~NkTLUlJqg7StxrhaNp~uOPYwB9yshwK9XqJDFuuj6it4E16eBK44TZ3It9yUeN5nIVIGNcDN5oyT~MIFod05~En11hRcfL~7IJbkRBl3TetCgVsnkY1BLGnJrQBwq9BJbluZiIsgnQizlWMg7RXTQFviS9sxtfaBoEzz~rx7~chUhTqrOcPsfBw35~4PzTAbz3zYU5CwyYaHR9MwodKVKLlSWF-xdKca0DueFrBAfE4hCS-RNeWGsiMQQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar (org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/45fecfa5c8217ce1f3652ab95179790ec8cc0dec0384bca51cbeb94a293d9f2f?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvNDVmZWNmYTVjODIxN2NlMWYzNjUyYWI5NTE3OTc5MGVjOGNjMGRlYzAzODRiY2E1MWNiZWI5NGEyOTNkOWYyZj9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmpheGItcnVudGltZS0yLjMuMS5qYXIlMjIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE2MDcxMDczMjJ9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn19fV19&Signature=NF27s5JS9R9kX8A9qyyQ3FniTOvy8GBvk48YKJwfahWuktRayuDfBGdIjjA10ZHYR~V-3jaxJTiP-zFncn6SUw-Em51nm4vZPNXbfXIUaxack0k9QvEQ9Rv4H5QUNrb9qfjjUjwRs2hSn1h380MtyognFj9Ai1MEogrmkSxN33OpUG6zGYZSPgNsktev37JMRQex5j1-ORXQam6yqAWSZpY9xj6j4Ppme7xvjAYxinlghNNy0BRc0FvqJFa~CTgy1cNCjBG2NIcfHop~Hv1ULRMAVSqIb~q1STmMcfY3htHLxv7gqGEDbgLPBzIK8l~h9zJmf5gwMHo33IpFY4IBAA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/3856a7349ebacd6d1be6802b2fed9c4dc2c5a564ea92b6b945ac988243d4b16b?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvMzg1NmE3MzQ5ZWJhY2Q2ZDFiZTY4MDJiMmZlZDljNGRjMmM1YTU2NGVhOTJiNmI5NDVhYzk4ODI0M2Q0YjE2Yj9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmtvdGxpbi1zdGRsaWItMS4zLjcyLmphciUyMiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTYwNzEwNzEyNH0sIklwQWRkcmVzcyI6eyJBV1M6U291cmNlSXAiOiIwLjAuMC4wLzAifX19XX0_&Signature=MHHfjlaCr~9DuYgkjCKxGWqOYkDd9GfRyiBpDUAy1VpVH-mDz0s6vRCwfsppm6yzo1kyMj6FOtTLLTqP3LktkxaQ-q9ApT81riDYKAANU6nc-DxgdrTWZvuHPQ8hoz8mGnW6bykYp7HH3TP4oxMT3AW6wV3BCpeE4PuXT7hkDMqh5gztMozW6OHtEbmgHcyBu-P5SDnz6xR7EhOwBRAOoSsJQaglJ4kg7YJj0y29ggEwOTzRU5YrjwlwuEYL8Iq5OXJVhA5HSrzPwOVtW-YIahzmG5d8ws-LgKHDzsaIOLqwddWsOvcCOiuY9JygZ0KOCHna~FLui8HDPZvadO~FQQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download proguard-base-6.0.3.jar (net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:6.0.3)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/6.0.3/proguard-base-6.0.3.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/75bc89695fa66e75374ecda439b802406f0ab1d826dd386eed0a23b1f0a9d264?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22proguard-base-6.0.3.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvNzViYzg5Njk1ZmE2NmU3NTM3NGVjZGE0MzliODAyNDA2ZjBhYjFkODI2ZGQzODZlZWQwYTIzYjFmMGE5ZDI2ND9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMnByb2d1YXJkLWJhc2UtNi4wLjMuamFyJTIyIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNjA3MTA2OTU2fSwiSXBBZGRyZXNzIjp7IkFXUzpTb3VyY2VJcCI6IjAuMC4wLjAvMCJ9fX1dfQ__&Signature=r~advtmMUN-s1Z91lWCSaVnb1Eq3qFEXM2J-7F9J2yyp2wH78FzM-3ibZfGLjT-rhDwGTkCrobVWnCwpi0A2EJGdAbMc0pFqVzuc93eTCqrso3AktvXEBTq4HWqtEBF2QA5TNg27UvefQan1OuuoCHABM5MW5rgACoRzqABiRXzgJybTxLCpa8-VYA2qH6zTqU5Qdlip1YuhU3cP6vI7~8JOw98lHI7p0S8Ra5QI572o~x2XhYN8zOQg80kgcmjd09jRtFz1INyY4eOo0z6of5MApzBBipErO2V3oG~pHYsb2MZQKHBacA5zu~fSEKUTro9nsPnVMyfjUTAkKE502Q__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download jdom2-2.0.6.jar (org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jdom/jdom2/2.0.6/jdom2-2.0.6.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/6f14738ec2e9dd0011e343717fa624a10f8aab64?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22jdom2-2.0.6.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvNmYxNDczOGVjMmU5ZGQwMDExZTM0MzcxN2ZhNjI0YTEwZjhhYWI2ND9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmpkb20yLTIuMC42LmphciUyMiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTYwNzEwNjg2Mn0sIklwQWRkcmVzcyI6eyJBV1M6U291cmNlSXAiOiIwLjAuMC4wLzAifX19XX0_&Signature=T9sCQQMjCF~7DiEnzWHkSt4B-Jyj7dzp2nXNTvGpCwY5vqZxWWczEiUfV2gbTKVfW5hobREIG58LjLPtm6UqMEwvQHFdec1FwaBgqxrI~aFKBle9eJqUWS-NT-a0j-cWSfEiXNhfFBzWQT6xS80lXJbhWwBw~TLWPW6gV0EilE2O88LpVMUvTgWkW0wrbPyq~peBuP~UaVmeQZJgYAT~EnS3NVFTF1fCf0M4fN84WxF~R0rNJh~Bkuzx0wJ1A1XB3bN5o-WzlUt5eYEzWzymO9Pif5aS0R5O2LrIzW6gK8ZPLMWCnyUG1bgRoQVqNZiwoxp-JwNbtGIHu7JT3WhmgA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download commons-compress-1.12.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.12/commons-compress-1.12.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/2c1542faf343185b7cab9c3d55c8ae5471d6d095d3887a4adefdbdf2984dc0b6?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22commons-compress-1.12.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvMmMxNTQyZmFmMzQzMTg1YjdjYWI5YzNkNTVjOGFlNTQ3MWQ2ZDA5NWQzODg3YTRhZGVmZGJkZjI5ODRkYzBiNj9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMmNvbW1vbnMtY29tcHJlc3MtMS4xMi5qYXIlMjIiLCJDb25kaXRpb24iOnsiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE2MDcxMDcxMjZ9LCJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMC4wLjAuMC8wIn19fV19&Signature=ZGutyvLCb4bszF-hh5TABjI6mSOD~ZCd~t606dJlsjx0Lp0SHfq8SGDINhAF8bsOrh7xDauB4c~hTfe3ZT~DCP78c74Od3lCqnpu9GfmriNE7Ot6ceZexEQZerv0StdorlND927vkbwmsEO1d6IbMzB77uiYXLYh0zShFHrvG57lNJaSG72YRbhq-P7HrT5UxXjWJVqbIv-g305BGQOXEz32BHFTgl89e7Bipy6MuGUDXsGSFwTzMdoY6iWDdi8V0ROKSCP11-Y9hTJVb446FVXuTlfuBg6xmpqnC-JMO4ySfDDtJj47peerypmNaAIUubA~wV9s9nhiiT6kDC2w0Q__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download trove4j-20160824.jar (org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/trove4j/trove4j/20160824/trove4j-20160824.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/1917871c8deb468307a584680c87a44572f5a8b0b98c6d397fc0f5f86596dbe7?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22trove4j-20160824.jar%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvMTkxNzg3MWM4ZGViNDY4MzA3YTU4NDY4MGM4N2E0NDU3MmY1YThiMGI5OGM2ZDM5N2ZjMGY1Zjg2NTk2ZGJlNz9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMnRyb3ZlNGotMjAxNjA4MjQuamFyJTIyIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoxNjA3MTA2ODU2fSwiSXBBZGRyZXNzIjp7IkFXUzpTb3VyY2VJcCI6IjAuMC4wLjAvMCJ9fX1dfQ__&Signature=nMMEdoUUXLf~rnOYj-0lU3aiZu-6GgQEI6Y6eSzYqf9B1BM59CuT47BmhdEUa5igbYGJ-pLy27htoRBmLnoGskxv1AH9YwUtGxsyg0D-tLyYDdt00nQYyN~03klFQkrFTqpMUEuN5GbKuYNs1enCOzg5sg0sdL-yVJNc6Y2rmCePYMza-zREHi7G7AjFGvuI58QIftWmtngEihGZyZ0PV1qNyaZWwFFUhLKuv-x0dNCyQiY~AXSXOwWB6mVmoI0a3nrNk9HLjKGYGVO~holRR1MwbAxsoayIF5cg8QruN0kI1~HEIFmt7WT9puMw8Bw2h-Zr6sWnC2a3gl~avoYc8w__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA'.
            > Connection reset
```

It looks like GET requests contains some invalid ID information, like `Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA`, but how can I address that?
There is really massive error log, can't publish it all due to message's body size limit.

Should I download the missing files manually? But where to place them?